# Убрать переключение на следующий EditText

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-edittext

У меня есть 2 элемента EditText и 2 обработчика на нажатие Enter для них на клаве.
Пример обработчика вот:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    //...
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Я не хочу, чтобы при нажатии Enter фокус переходил на следующий EditText(нужно чтобы он убрался с выбранного и не перешел на следующий).
Этого я добился, прописав в xml `android:imeOptions="actionDone"`
И тут возникла проблема, что в обработчике перестала работать проверка:

`((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER))`
Задача:сделать так, чтобы после нажатия Enter фокус не переходил на следующий EditText, при этом был указан параметр `android:imeOptions="actionGo"`

Answer (score 1):

Долго думал и шаманил. В итоге получилось.
Вот так теперь выглядит этот кусок кода:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                    //...
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

А теперь объясню в чем разница и особенности.

1. Убрал `(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)`, без этого условия на следующую строку больше не переходит.
2. Если убрать `return true;` внутри условия, то даже без условия из пункта 1 будет переход.

Как итог - условие `(event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)`надо убрать, за присутствием `return true;` внутри условия проследить.

Answer (score 0):

android:imeOptions="actionDone"

insert in editText xml

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]